# TF15013: The requested Team Foundation Server is not registered with the proxy server

Tags: proxy

I have configured TFS Proxy server and have set the source control setting of my local VS client. Also TFS Application server & TFS Proxy server both are in same network Domain.
But when i am taking get latest of any team project and second time taking the get latest of same team project at different machine but files are downloading Main server and giving below warning.

TF15013: The requested Team Foundation Server is not registered with the proxy server.

Can Anyone help me out how to resolve this issue & make fast get latest.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you download the project files for the first time in this "different" machine? Please double check if you have set the the source control setting to use the proxy server for files downloads for your second client machine. Also, you can try to delete Team Foundation folder in all your clients under %HOMEPATH%\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply....I tried the same but issue still persists.

Comment: So, what's the response for my first question, Can you download the project files for the first time in this "different" machine?, or just can not download the files in whichever machine for the second time?

Comment: Yes Andy, first time i took get latest of a team project at different machine & took the get latest of same project at second different machine so the files should be downloaded from proxy server but it didn't. Showing only message in VS output window. The source control proxy 'tfsproxy013357' is not responding, so the request will be sent to the main server.  Please verify your settings.
Additional information:
  TF15013: The requested Team Foundation Server is not registered with the proxy server.”

Comment: Are you using the same user account for the second time to get the latest version in VS client ? Please try 1) create local accounts on Proxy that matches (both username and password should match) the credential provided by TFS clients,

2) Create a local account on TFS AT that matches Proxy service account(both username and password should match) and add this account to “TFS Valid Users” group

Comment: No I am not using the same account second time. Let me explain my purpose..I have around 10 developers all are having their domin ADID & connect with TFS Client. Also i have set the source setting of all developers VS client. But i have taken get latest of team project at one proxy server using proxy account. My intention is if any developer take get latest as per his need using his/her ADID account then it should be coming through Proxy server cache location..hope now this is quite understandable explain..please suggest now...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the proxy command to configure your client to use a proxy server: see [Proxy Command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/proxy-command)
eg :

```
c:\projects>tf proxy /add http://server:8081 /default:global /collection:http://tfsserver:8080/
```

If that still not work, recommend you to reconfigure the Proxy, you must use service accounts to install Team Foundation Server, and Team Foundation Server Proxy. These service accounts become the identity for the installed component.

By default, every component uses a built-in account (such as Network Service) as its service account.Built-in accounts do not use passwords and already have the Log on as a service permission, making them easier to manage, especially in a domain environment. See [requirements](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements#accounts).

After that you can reference below link to configure the TFS proxy to work with Your TFS:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2016/10/12/how-to-configure-a-tfs-proxy-to-work-with-team-services/

**Update:**

TFS 2013 is Xaml build system, double chick the definition will pop up the definition to edit. TFS 2017 is vNext build system, it will redirect to web client build progress page. That's by design, not related to the source settings.

And as far as I know, there isn't the utility or third part tools can open the vNext build definition in VS directly, vNext build definition is task independent, you can edit it conveniently via web portal.

Comment: I have tried all suggested steps even reconfigured TFS proxy & clear cache and %HOMEPATH%/appdata/local/microsoft/TFS folder but still the same message is showing in VS output window..:(The source control proxy 'tfsproxy013357.aptify.com' is not responding, so the request will be sent to the main server.  Please verify your settings.
Additional information:
  TF15013: The requested Team Foundation Server is not registered with the proxy server.

Comment: Make sure the users have permission to access the proxy server, see [Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252490.aspx)part. Also check if add the firewall exceptions for your client and proxy server. Also try 1) create local accounts on Proxy that matches (both username and password should match) the credential provided by TFS clients, 2) Create a local account on TFS AT that matches Proxy service account(both username and password should match) and add this account to “TFS Valid Users” group

Comment: @Andy-- Now i am not getting above mentioned error simply getting output of getlatest in output window. But how can i make sure the get latest of second machine of same project is downloading from tfsproxy server cache location? Please suggest.

Comment: @Dhurva If you have set the source control setting in the local VS client, and it works to get latest, then the downloading would be from tfs proxy server cache location. You can also try to check the logs somewhere in VS client machine or Proxy server, try to check event viewer.

Comment: @Andy--Hello Andy Actually i have upgraded our TFS Application server from 2013 to 2017 and still client is VS2015 so there is no major issue once we trigger any build from VS & try to see build progress the moment when i double click on build definition then it redirect to TFS2017 web client build progress page. but before upgrde it was opening in VS itself. I guess there in source setting needs to be set so that build progress can see in VS2015 itself.  Please suggest if you know any thought what i need to do?     Thanks,

Comment: @Dhurva That's as designed, TFS 2013 is Xaml build system, double chick the definition will pop up the definition to edit. TFS 2017 is vNext build system, it will redirect to web client build progress page. That's normal, not related to the source settings.

Comment: @Andy--Thanks, but is there any utility or third party tool ? after installing this build progress can be open in Visual Studio itsel..

Comment: @Dhurva As far as I know, there isn't such an utility or tool to achieve that, you can edit the vNext build definition directly via web portal.